# Is the documentation for EntitySpaces still available anywhere?

Tags: .net, documentation, entityspaces

[EntitySpaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EntitySpaces)

> EntitySpaces is an object-relational mapping tool, whose architecture
>   can be used when writing an ASP.NET, .NET Framework or .NET Compact
>   Framework application.
>
> On September 21, 2012, EntitySpaces announced they would dissolve on
>   December 31, 2012 and their products would transition to open source.

**Does anybody know if any of the supporting documentation is available anywhere else? As of open source transition these links are all down now;**

[Developer Documentation site](http://www.developer.entityspaces.net/documentation/Default.aspx)

[The EntitySpaces API Reference](http://www.entityspaces.net/Documentation/EntitySpaces/index.html)

[Getting Started PDF](http://www.entityspaces.net/documentation/GetStarted.pdf)

Even the link to the announcement;

[EntitySpaces to shutdown and move to another server](http://www.entityspaces.net/blog/2012/09/21/EntitySpaces+To+Shutdown+Move+To+Open+Source.aspxhttp://www.entityspaces.net/blog/2012/09/21/EntitySpaces+To+Shutdown+Move+To+Open+Source.aspx)

Comment: I was really hoping that someone somewhere would have a copy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the EntitySpaces home page, download the product, it's totally free, installs everything, even the profiler, full source, and the documentation, just see the EntitySpaces 2012 menu after installation.

PS: Use the direct download link under the donwnload button otherwise Download.com tries to get you to install annoying toolbars and such.

Answer (score 5):

http://esdocs.pixeo.be/ (For anyone who just wants a link to the documentation)

Comment: Why the minus vote people? Thanks Pixeo

Comment: You're welcome CodeBlend. Hope it's allowed to put it online like this. I just think it might help people like this.

Answer (score 4):

Mr. Blend,

You can find everything on GitHub.

https://github.com/EntitySpaces/EntitySpaces-CompleteSource

Lance

Comment: Thank you for the link, at the moment the documentation has not been uploaded https://github.com/EntitySpaces/EntitySpaces-CompleteSource/blob/master/Documentation/Help/Placeholder.txt https://github.com/EntitySpaces/EntitySpaces-CompleteSource/blob/master/Documentation/HelpLight/Placeholder.txt